# get_current_user_id() returns 0 inside AJAX request. Why?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I built a WooCommerce plugin that modifies prices for products depending on user meta. 
This works well, except during AJAX product search. On further investigation, I discovered that get_current_user_id() returns 0 inside wp_doing_ajax()

What could be causing this? ideas? Thank you.

To give more info: this is only happening on a particular customer's website. On a test website of my own using the same theme, the issue is not happening. Still, I want to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Ajax is a separate HTTP call from the actual call from the browser you can assign the `get_current_user_id()` to the js variable using `wp_localize_script` and access it globally in any JS file.

Comment: Have you tried this-      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
        // Not logged in.
    } else {
        // Logged in.
    }

Comment: @mujuonly I did try wp_get_current_user(), it's the same result.

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan I understand, but since this is a plugin, I do not have access to theme JS files that control AJAX search